# Ruby selenium webdriver unable to find Mozilla geckodriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, selenium, ubuntu-16.04

I have geckodriver installed in my development directory

```
ls | grep geckodriver
geckodriver
geckodriver-v0.11.1-linux64.tar.gz
```

I also exported to the $PATH variable

```
export PATH=$PATH:~/Development/geckodriver
```

But when I attempt to initialize an instance of the webdriver on rails console of my project I get this

> driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
>
> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:  Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver
> What's the issue here.

Comment: did you downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have `selenium-webdriver-3.0.0.beta3.1` which is only for Firefox 48 and later (and not yet properly working). Fallback to `selenium-webdriver` version `2.53.4` and try again.

And also try this..

- In the terminal change directory path to the directory where gem was
  installed
- Run `gem uninstall selenium-webdriver`
- Run `gem install selenium-webdriver -v 2.53.4`

Answer (score 15):

You have to make sure that `geckodriver` is in your `PATH`.

In my case you can see that `/usr/local/bin` is already in my path:

```
$echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

So simply moving `geckodriver` into `/usr/local/bin` makes it accessible.

```
mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: super.. we should add this as mandatory step for mac ;) in setup itself

Comment: This solution works for me, I'm using macOS. Other solutions like adding the geckodriver path to PATH somehow don't work.

Answer (score 6):

You can now move to`selenium-webdriver 3.4.3` which is the latest version. However, you still need the GeckoDriver because there no native extensions of Selenium in FF. You can also add the `geckodriver-helper` gem to your GemFile. Check https://github.com/DevicoSolutions/geckodriver-helper .

Be aware of that there are still some issues that have to be fixed when you use the combination of ***Selenium3 & FF48+*** combination and can affect your tests like double-click and modal windows.

Answer (score 3):

Download geckodriver and add it to your PATH

```
cd ~/Downloads/
wget https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.24.0/geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz
tar -zxvf geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz
sudo mv geckodriver /usr/local/bin/
```

---

Note: That's currently the path for the latest release. If you need another release, modify the download path accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me if I add this part to the command:
    `PATH=$PATH:/home/username/folder/driver cucumber features/new.feature`

Answer (score 0):

After download the "geckodriver" I unzipped the driver into new folder  "webdrivers". Second, in the system path, create a new entry that points to the new "geckodriver" directory. 
Finally restart the command prompt after modifying the environment variable. 
Maybe the last past could be the trick