# Receiving error when working with selenium-webdriver. Unable to find mozilla geckodriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, geckodriver

I am following a [tutorial](https://youtu.be/J_gDfWgTU2c) on how to use RSpec with Ruby.
We are learning how to work with webdriver, however I am receiving an error when I try to run my project. I was wondering can you see If I am missing something?thanks

Firstly I will tell you more on the background of the project.

I am using the IDE Jetbrains RubyMine to build the project.
And I have the following versions of the required programs installed:

Ruby 2.2.6
Rspec 3.6
selenium-webdriver 3.0.0

I have set up an Rspec test with the following code:

```
require 'rspec'
require 'selenium-webdriver'

describe 'My zoo site' do

  it 'should open browser and click on contact' do
    # create a webdriver driver
    driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox)

  end
end
```

When I run this test code, I get the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:         

Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. 

Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases 
and place it somewhere on your PATH. 

More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.
```

So after seeing this error I went to the [geckodriver releases url](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) as instructed and downloadeded the geckodriver-v0.17.0 file for windows 32bit.

I placed the exectuable file called geckodriver.exe in the following directory: C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe

Then I went into My computer->Properties->Advanced system settings->Environment variables->Path (in system variables) and I added C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe

however i'm still getting the same error. 
I found a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310586/ruby-selenium-webdriver-unable-to-find-mozilla-geckodriver) but the solution of "installing selenium-webdriver version 2.53.0" did not solve it for me.
(Also note: The version of firefox I have is 53.0.3.)

Am i missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can troubleshoot this by checking your path in your command line (probably `cmd.exe`) by outputting your path using:

```
echo %path%
```

For something like git bash its probably more like:

```
echo $PATH
```

Anyways, IMO it has something to do with what you put into your PATH.
Usually, you just put directories there, ie. you would just say `C:\geckodriver\` and omit the executable.

As soon as you can call `geckodriver` from your CMD, RSpec should be able to as well.

Comment: thank you. well actually yesterday I installed selenium-webdriver 2.45.0 and tried to run the test again. The firefox window did open up but I get a different error now saying "unable to obtain stable firefox connection in 60 seconds"..... So I think the geckodriver is being detected properly. But  taking your good advice I have changed the path to C:\geckodriver anyway. Thanks for the information. I see it is successfully in the path when I run echo %path% too. Any ideas about the new error?

Comment: I think you should try to go with super-up-to-date versions of both geckodriver, selenium-webdriver and Firefox, your selenium-webdriver version seems way behind (3.4.0 seems to be the most recent). Making the versions sync up is probably important.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for the advice however it wasnt working with the latest versions unfortunately. I didn't find an answer unfortunately. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

Put your executable in the same directory as your code. And then add the executable path parameter to your Firefox object

```
myDriver=driver.Firefox(executable_path=os.getcwd()+"/geckodriver")

myDriver.get("someUrl.blabla") #Do something
```

just make sure you have os imported

This way you'll never have to worry about whether it is in your path or not. Because it is already in your directory. It makes things easier if you want to share it with someone or run it on another machine.