# Rails 5, Rspec-rails, Capybara, Selenium-webdriver - Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I try test my new gem, with use js.
But got errors

- rails 5.1.5
- rspec-rails 3.7.2
- capybara 2.18.0
- selenium-webdriver 3.10.0

app/spec/rails_helper.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

...
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'support/factory_bot'
```

app/spec/features/view_helper_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe DynamicNestedForms::ViewHelpers do
  # it "does something" do
  it "displays patient" do
    patient = create(:patient)
    visit edit_patient_path(patient)

    expect(page).to have_selector("input[value='#{patient.name}']")
  end

  it "displays physicians", :js => true do
    patient = create(:patient)
    physician = create(:physician)
    visit edit_patient_path(patient)

    fill_in "autocomplete_nested_content", with: physician[0..2]

    expect(page).to have_selector(".ui-menu-item-wrapper", text: physician.name)
  end
end
```

I get this error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
        Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver. Please download the server from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere on your PATH. More info at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.
```

Comment: Did you already download `geckodriver` as described above in your error log? If you already did but still had errors, try this potential duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41310586/ruby-selenium-webdriver-unable-to-find-mozilla-geckodriver

Comment: @Jay-ArPolidario I download archive from this link [GitHub release page](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), but I don't know what I need do next

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu, try this on how to install `geckodriver` https://askubuntu.com/questions/870530/how-to-install-geckodriver-in-ubuntu

Comment: Oh, sorry. Forgot to specify the path to the file. It work.

Comment: Good to hear it worked! :)

Answer (score 3):

The easiest solution to this is to add the `webdrivers` gem to your project which will automatically download/install the relevant driver program and inform selenium-webdriver of its location - https://github.com/titusfortner/webdrivers